# Unexpected environment variable unset

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, tee

In Bash, some global variable will be unexpected unset after the command `tee` runs.

Test code as follows:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
function set_global_variable(){
        GLOBAL_VARIABLE="global_variable"
        echo "set GLOBAL_VARIABLE($GLOBAL_VARIABLE)"
}

function get_global_variable(){
        echo "get GLOBAL_VARIABLE($GLOBAL_VARIABLE)"
}

function normal_test(){
        unset GLOBAL_VARIABLE
        set_global_variable
        get_global_variable
}

function unnormal_test(){
        unset GLOBAL_VARIABLE
        set_global_variable |tee random_file
        get_global_variable
}

echo "normal_test"
normal_test

echo "unnormal_test"
unnormal_test
```

The result:

```shell
normal_test
set GLOBAL_VARIABLE(global_variable)
get GLOBAL_VARIABLE(global_variable)
unnormal_test
set GLOBAL_VARIABLE(global_variable)
get GLOBAL_VARIABLE()
```

The value of GLOBAL_VARIABLE in `unnormal_test` is null, why?

Comment: In a pipe, commands are executed in sub-shells, which means that any changes they make to the environment are not visible in the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
set_global_variable |tee random_file
```

When this line is ran, bash will create a subshell for each component of the pipeline and run them there. So `set_global_variable` will actually set the variable, but it will do that in a separate process. When you are run `get_global_variable` in the next line, you are still in the original process that was not affected by this.

Here's a simpler example of that effect:

```
true | a=1
echo $a
```

This will print nothing for the same reasons explained above. On the other hand:

```
true | { a=1; echo $a; }
```

will print 1, because `echo $a` is ran from the same subshell as `a=1`. The last example is not very useful in practice though.

So a general rule, do not set variables in a subshell.